# Execute multiple terminal commands at once with "&" and get an ordered result

Tags: bash, terminal, parallel-processing

I need to execute multiple commands (like 2000 at a time) at once and really fast.

One way is to execute them with a "&" between each command which is really fast but I get the results (json format) mixed up so that I can not just load the output as json.

I also tried to use 'parallel'. With that command I get the commands in correct json but it takes way longer.

Is there a way to execute the commands with "&" and not get the output
all mixed up?

Comment: Not if they are all writing to standard output, because the shell doesn't know how to merge the multiple writers. Redirect each command's output to a separate file, and concatenate them when (or as) the commands compelte.

Comment: The bash `wait` command will be helpful in this situation.

Comment: If the order is important then you should run the commands sequentially. That said, if the order is not that important (for ex. populating a JSON hash or an unordered array) then it is possible to merge everything correctly using a file, but each command needs write its output at once and that output has to be less than the maximum number of bytes guarantied by O_APPEND (OS dependent).

Answer (score 1):

I doubt spawning 2000 process might be a good idea and parallel would give you more control, having said that, something simple like this could be used

```
N=2000
for ((n=0; n<N; n++))
do
    mycommand $n > out-$n.txt &
done
wait
for ((n=0; n<N; n++))
do
    cat out-$n.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a message command to JSON with the **jq** command.

I don't know how you are calling your commands. But you can add additional objects to JSON.

```
command |jq '. + {"key2": "value2"}'
```

Example code

```
command | jq '. + {"commands": \"$(script execute)\"}'
```